# How to properly unwrap an optional in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class, option-type

I am learning the basics of Java and I am exploring `Optionals and abstract classes` so I came across the following issue,

I have this code

```
import java.util.Optional;

public abstract class Animal {
    abstract void makeSound();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Horse horse = new Horse();
        
        
        Animal[] animals = {dog, cat, horse};
        
        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            
            Optional<Dog> _dog = animal instanceof Dog ? Optional.of((Dog) animal) : null;
            Optional<Cat> _cat = animal instanceof Cat ? Optional.of((Cat) animal) : null;
            Optional<Horse> _horse = animal instanceof Horse ? Optional.of((Horse) animal) : null;
            
            if (_dog.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println("it is a Dog");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it is NOT a Dog");
            }
                        
            animal.makeSound();
        }
    
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    String speed = "Fast";
    @Override
    void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Neighing...");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String color = "Brown";
    @Override
    void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Barking...");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    Integer lives = 9;
    @Override
    void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Mewoing......");
    }
}
```

I was expecting to see the prints on the console "It is a Dog" followed by 2 "It is not a Dog" Since I'm using the method `.isPresent()` on optionals,

But I got 1 print and then a `NullPointerException`:

That's what I got printed:

```
Start
it is a Dog
Barking...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.helloworldeclipse.Animal.main(Animal.java:24)
```

Shouldn't isPresent be safe? is there a better way to cast abstract classes to subclasses in situations similar like this?

I don't get why it's not working.. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance for all the answers..

Comment: You should assign `_dog`, `_cat` and `_horse` to `Optional.empty()` instead of null when the type does not match.

Comment: An `Optional` variable/field/parameter should **never** be `null`, that would basically wreck the whole reason for its existance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning `null` to an `Optional` reference when the `instanceof` check fails.

You have at least two options:

1. Use [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#empty()) instead of `null`

   ```java
   Optional<Dog> dog = animal instanceof Dog ? Optional.of((Dog) animal) : Optional.empty();
   ```
2. Use Optional's [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) methods:

   ```java
   Optional<Dog> dog = Optional.of(animal)
       .filter(Dog.class::isInstance)
       .map(Dog.class::cast);
   ```

   The predicate `Dog.class::isInstance` checks if the given instance, which is the value within the `Optional`, is an instance of `Dog`. This is [`equivalent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) to `instanceof`. Then `Dog.class::cast` casts the given object to a `Dog` instance.

---

Note: If `animal` itself could be `null`, then you should use [`Optional::ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T)) instead of [`Optional::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#of(T)).

Comment: I think I'm too used to swift )

Thank you very much, 
the second option is even more compact and readable 

Comment: @Lucas I totally agree with you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use null, use `Optional<T>.empty()` instead, read here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're checking if dog.isPresent but you're also potentially assigning null to dog when the value is not dog. i.e on second iteration.

```java
Optional<Dog> dog = animal instanceof Dog ? Optional.of((Dog) animal) : Optional.empty();
```